Shannon source coding theorem and differential entropy
Loosely speaking, Shannon's source encoding theorem says that there is an encoder with rate at least $H(x)$ such that $n$ repetitions of the source can be mapped to at least $nH(X)$ bits of binary bits, such that the message can be recovered with high probability.
More precisely, here is a screen grab from Wikipedia:

Note that $H(X$) is the Shannon entropy in the discrete case and the differential entropy $H(X) = -\int p(x) \log p(x) dx$ were $p(x)$ is the pdf of $X$ in the continuous case.
However, is this correct? As we know, differential entropy can be negative (see Wikipedia article on an example). So what does it mean to have a negative rate for an encoder?

I cannot even make sense of "message can be recovered" when the source is a series of random values drawn from a continuous distribution: that ought to be impossible, period.

@whuber I'm not sure I understand your statement. Sure we have to impose some cut-off on the granularity in which we're storing a continuous number, but sending messages from a continuous distribution is what happens in real life, no? like analog TV or radio signals (oscillating EM fields etc.).

The difficulty is that the limiting value of the entropy of discretizations of those signals is not necessarily (or even usually) the differential entropy.

Then could you be so kind as to teach me what the problem entropy should be?

What do you mean by "problem entropy"?  Regardless, Shannon's theorem applies only to finite alphabets.

sorry, typo. I mean "proper". So the wikipedia article is wrong then?

Well, clearly something is wrong, as you point out!
